# Props don't update when state updates in React

Tags: reactjs, state, jsx, react-props

I'm passing some values from my state in the App component to the GetWordContainer component as props. With these props, I set the state in my child component. However, the state in GetWordContainer only updates once. How can I have the state in the child component continue to update when the state in App.js changes?

App.js

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    redirect: {},
    word: '',
    error: '',
    info: [],
    partOfSpeech: [],
    versions: [],
    shortdef: "",
    pronunciation: "",
  }

  setRedirect = redirect =>{{
    this.setState({redirect})
  }
  // console.log(this.state.redirect);
  console.log(this.state.word);
}
  

  handleUpdate = values => 
    this.setState({...values})
    


render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Route 
          render={ routeProps => <Redirector redirect={this.state.redirect} setRedirect={this.setRedirect} {...routeProps} />}
        />
        <header>
          <nav>
            <Link to='/'>My Dictionary</Link>
          </nav>
        </header>

        <main>
        <Route
            render = { routeProps =>
              !routeProps.location.state?.alert ? '' :
              <div>
                { routeProps.location.state.alert }
              </div>
            }
          />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={ routeProps => 
              <Home 
                setRedirect={this.setRedirect} 
                handleUpdate={this.handleUpdate} 
                {...routeProps} />} 
              />
            <Route exact path="/definition/:word" render={routeProps => 
              <GetWordContainer 
                setRedirect={this.setRedirect}
                handleUpdate={this.handleUpdate}
                word={this.state.word} 
                partOfSpeech={this.state.partOfSpeech}
                versions={this.state.versions}
                shortdef={this.state.shortdef}
                pronunciation={this.state.pronunciation}
                {...routeProps} />} 
              />
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

GetWordContainer.js

```
class GetWordContainer extends Component {

//this state only updates once 
state = {
  word: this.props.word,
  info: this.props.info,
  partOfSpeech: this.props.parOfSpeech,
  versions: this.props.versions,
  shortdef: this.props.shortdef,
  pronunciation: this.props.pronunciation,
}


render (){

  return (

      <div>
        <Search
          handleUpdate={this.props.handleUpdate}
          setRedirect={this.props.setRedirect}
        />
        <div>
             {this.state.word}
        </div>
        <div>
             {this.state.partOfSpeech}
        </div>
        <div>
             {this.state.versions.map((v, i) => <div key={i}>{v}</div>)}
        </div>
        <div>
             {this.state.pronunciation}
        </div>
        <div>
             {this.state.shortdef}
        </div>
      </div>
  );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor lifecycle method runs only once - during the initialisation of the component. If you are expecting new data from parent component, you can re-render your child by using `componentDidUpdate()` or `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.word || this.props.word) {
   this.setState({
     word
   })
  }
}
```

I notice that your child component is not manipulating the props, it is just a display-only container. Why don't you just pass the props and display it directly rather than taking the longest route? Your child component can be a functional component:

```
const GetWordContainer = (props) => {
  return (
      <div>
        <Search
          handleUpdate={props.handleUpdate}
          setRedirect={props.setRedirect}
        />
        <div>
             {props.word}
        </div>
        <div>
             {props.partOfSpeech}
        </div>
        <div>
             {props.versions.map((v, i) => <div key={i}>{v}</div>)}
        </div>
        <div>
             {props.pronunciation}
        </div>
        <div>
             {props.shortdef}
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used a componentDidUpdate function. I had to change it slightly to fit my code but it did the job!

Answer (score 3):

The issue you're facing is that the `state` value in the `GetWordContainer` component is instantiated on the initial render. There are exceptions but in general, React will reuse the same component across renders when possible. This means the component is not re-instantiated, so the `state` value does not change across re-renders.

One solution to this problem is to use the appropriate lifecycle method to handle when the component re-renders and update state appropriately: [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

However, since it appears you want to render the props directly, I would recommend avoiding state entirely in `GetWordContainer`.

For example:

```
class GetWordContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Search
          handleUpdate={this.props.handleUpdate}
          setRedirect={this.props.setRedirect}
        />
        <div>{this.props.word}</div>
        <div>{this.props.partOfSpeech}</div>
        <div>
          {this.props.versions.map((v, i) => (
            <div key={i}>{v}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div>{this.props.pronunciation}</div>
        <div>{this.props.shortdef}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @skovy! I'm actually trying to have state in the GetWordContainer because eventually I want users to be able to visit the direct url for example, http://localhost:3000/definition/word and I think I need the state in that container for that reason. I've tried componentWillReceiveProps but haven't gotten anything to work.

Comment: This component can still have state, but I would recommend putting only the values that need to be local to this component (or it's children) as state within this component. For all values passed to it, it can use those values directly. As for the URL, you can interpolate the prop value (eg: `"localhost:3000/definition/" + this.props.word`).